# Parallel Programming in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, parallel-processing, codeigniter-2

I am making an Web App in Codeigniter PHP Framework. 
When a user clicks on Login Button, there are 5-6 functions that gets called before serving the dashboard to the user

Ex

```
/*When user clicks login button */
 $this->setSession($u_id);
 $this->getUserData($u_id);
 $this->getUserFriends($u_id);
 $this->sendEmail($u_id);
 $this->showDashboard($data);
```

Now the above four functions are independent functions..they dont interact with each other in any way. So system would still be in consistent mode if those 3 functions gets executed in any order or gets executed parallely.

So how can i make those 3 functions execute simultaneously in Codeigniter if its possible ??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not support background processes but check this workaround:
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/66539/#327527

```
function background() {
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
  log_message('error', 'Unable to connect to server');
  return;
}
$request = "GET /SendSMS/index HTTP/1.1\r\n"
  ."Host: www.example.com\r\n"
  ."Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($fp, $request);
fclose($fp);
}
```